# Getting centroid of area and info in popup in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, popup, centroids

I'm trying to get the centroids of each of the features of a polygon layer, and the popup with its info inside: but I'm not able to show those centroids. Something is wrong in my code, the variables are not integrated at the right place.. could you help me please?

I'm using those JS scripts: jquery.min.js, turf.min.js,leaflet.js

```
$.getJSON("paystrav.geojson", function(data){ 
   var centroids = { 
      type: 'FeatureCollection', 
      features: data.features.map(function(feat) { 
          return { 
              type: 'Feature', 
              properties: feat.properties, 
              geometry: turf.centroid(feat).geometry 
          } 
      }) 
  }; 
     function onEachFeature(feature, centroid) { 
         layer.bindPopup("<h2>" + feature.properties.NAME + "</h2><br>" + "Population: " + feature.properties.POP2005 + "<br><a href='" + feature.properties.link + "' target='_blank'>Go to the map</a><br><img src=" + feature.properties.image + " width='200px'/>"); 
    } 
        });
  var pays = L.geoJson(centroids, { 
onEachFeature: onEachFeature 
}); 
pays.addTo(map);
```

and a sample from the geojson :

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "paystrav",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 1, "NAME": "Ireland", "POP2005": 4143294, "link": "https://mappingforyou.eu/ukir", "flag": null, "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Connemara_sheeps.jpg/320px-Connemara_sheeps.jpg" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -9.656389, 53.222221 ], [ -9.663334, 53.221382 ], [ -9.688612, 53.222771 ], [ -9.695557, 53.223328 ] ] ] ] } },
```

Comment: @TomazicM thanks, done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `$.getJSON` method is async, all you have to do it to put GeoJSON layer `pays` creation and adding to the map inside result processing `function(data)` function.

Also in `onEachFeature` function your layer parameter is named `centroid`, so you have to use this when attaching popup to the layer, not `layer`.

So your code should look something like this:

```
$.getJSON("paystrav.geojson", function(data){ 
   var centroids = { 
    type: 'FeatureCollection', 
    features: data.features.map(function(feat) { 
      return { 
        type: 'Feature', 
        properties: feat.properties, 
        geometry: turf.centroid(feat).geometry 
      } 
    }) 
  }; 
 function onEachFeature(feature, centroid) { 
   centroid.bindPopup("<h2>" + feature.properties.NAME + "</h2><br>" + "Population: " + feature.properties.POP2005 + "<br><a href='" + feature.properties.link + "' target='_blank'>Go to the map</a><br><img src=" + feature.properties.image + " width='200px'/>"); 
 } 
  var pays = L.geoJson(centroids, { 
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature 
  });
  pays.addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly. thank you for your explanations...